# Stylesheet loader returns TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a little piece of code that is used to load a stylesheet chosen by a user from a list. The code loads the stylesheet onload, but recently I went to my website to test something new. After the page loaded I observed that the stylesheet didn't change, I looked in the console to ensure that the script was loaded, but instead saw an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of null " - and it was
>   spotted at this line of code: `return decodeURIComponent (
>   cookie_value[2] ) ;

I really don't know how to solve this I haven't changed anything in the main script. Here is the complete code:

```
 // *** TO BE CUSTOMISED ***

var style_cookie_name = "style" ;
var style_cookie_duration = 3000 ;

// *** END OF CUSTOMISABLE SECTION ***
// You do not need to customise anything below this line

function switch_style ( css_title )
{
var i, link_tag ;
for (i = 0, link_tag = document.getElementsByTagName("link") ;
i < link_tag.length ; i++ ) {
if ((link_tag[i].rel.indexOf( "stylesheet" ) != -1) &&
link_tag[i].title) {
link_tag[i].disabled = true ;
if (link_tag[i].title == css_title) {
link_tag[i].disabled = false ;
}
}
set_cookie( style_cookie_name, css_title,
style_cookie_duration );
}
}
function set_style_from_cookie()
{
var css_title = get_cookie( style_cookie_name );
if (css_title.length) {
switch_style( css_title );
}
}
function set_cookie ( cookie_name, cookie_value,
lifespan_in_days, valid_domain )
{
    var domain_string = valid_domain ?
                       ("; domain=" + valid_domain) : '' ;
    document.cookie = cookie_name +
"=" + encodeURIComponent( cookie_value ) +
"; max-age=" + 60 * 60 *
24 * lifespan_in_days +
"; path=/" + domain_string ;
}
function get_cookie ( cookie_name )
{
var cookie_string = document.cookie ;
if (cookie_string.length != 0) {
var cookie_value = cookie_string.match (
'(^|;)[\s]*' +
cookie_name +
'=([^;]*)' );
return decodeURIComponent ( cookie_value[2] ) ;
}
return '' ;
}
```

And please, be specific about the answers... I am not too much of a JavaScript guy, a buddy helped me to write the code.

Comment: Please include the code in the question, instead of just a link.

Comment: That means `cookie_value` is `null`. You must include the code here, otherwise if your site goes down, the question won't help future visitors. And please use a better title, currently it's too generic.

Answer (score 1):

cookie_value[2] is null

Try:

```
if(cookie_value != null && cookie_value.length>0) // do work
```

You could also wrap decodeURIComponent in a try catch

Comment: No, the error means `cookie_value` is null, so `cookie_value.length` will produce the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `cookie_value` is `null` because your regular expression match is not returning any results:

```
var cookie_value = cookie_string.match (
'(^|;)[\s]*' +
cookie_name +
'=([^;]*)' );
```